# Jenkins - build docker image - prevent seeing files owned by root

Tags: security, docker, jenkins, root

What are the options to secure Jenkins slave nodes that have docker daemon? Someone could launch docker container and essentially access files owned by root.

Environment and problem details:

- Jenkins
- Docker daemon available on Jenkins slaves
- Jenkins agent run as user “build”
- User build is added to group “docker” so that
  the jobs can build and start containers
- We are considering to use
  docker pipeline https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

**Problem:**

- A user can mount the server root as a docker volume
- They could execute a command like “rm -rf /hostroot/*” or print the contents of a secret file owned by root.
- Couple options:

  - **Option 1**: Use the –user argument to run the commands as a specific user, but since the Jenkinsfile is managed by development team this can’t be enforced strictly
  - **Option 2**: Enable user namespace on the docker daemon (there may be some permissions issues – especially on the workspace folder but some workarounds can be put in place)
    Do you use user namespace?
  - **Option 3**: build using AWS Fargate (need to look in to this a bit) – so the docker image is not built on Jenkins slave nodes and the build won’t affect the files on the nodes

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /:/hostroot'
             (args '—user 500 ' --> since Jenkinsfile is managed by development team, ensuring everyone puts this parameter is tricky… someone could forget to put it)
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'rm -rf /hostroot/*' --> delete the entire filesystem!
               sh 'cat /path/to/secret/file' --> see some files owned by root!

            }
        }
    }
}
```

A similar question was posted here but that is 2 years old and doesn't have a good answer:
[Building Docker images with Jenkins that runs inside a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960796/building-docker-images-with-jenkins-that-runs-inside-a-docker-container)